# On adding a Archer, it occupies space is all three army camp in Clash of Clan

Tags: clash-of-clans

Game: Clash Of Clan

I have a very big doubt about the way army troop accommodation works. I have 3 army camps (all 3 of size 110) when I add an archer why does it get added to all three camps. What this does is that my capacity is 330 but I am able to add just 110 troops. Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then the total amount of troops you are able to accommodate in your army camps is 110, as the army camps you currently have are probably 3 of level 3. When you train troops using your barracks the troops get evenly distributed over all the army camps, so if you train 1 archer it gets added to one of the camps, but if you train 3 each camp gets one. This means that your capacity is 110, and not 330.

Does this answer your question?

Yours sincerely,
Artos van Stel